# Does "Grit" give temporary hit points for heals that say "as if you had spent a healing surge?"

Tags: dnd-4e, feats, healing, temporary-hit-points

My question is about the interaction of a feat called [Grit](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/feat.aspx?id=380) and effects like the daily item power on [Dwarven Armor](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=1120).

> **Grit:** When you spend a healing surge to regain hit points, you also gain temporary hit points equal to your Constitution modifier.
>
> **Dwarven Armor Power (Healing)  Daily (Free Action)**:
> You regain hit points as if you had spent a healing surge.

Would I get the temporary hit points from Grit when using the Dwarven Armor power?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**No**,

As Okeefe noted, without the actual spending of the surge, Grit would not trigger.

Compare Grit to the Dwarven Durability feat, which would increase the hit points gained by the Dwarven Armor power as it modifies the surge value directly.

> **Dwarven Durability:** Increase your number of healing surges by two and your healing surge value by your Constitution modifier.

Comment: Not what I wanted to hear, but it makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

No, because you didn't spend a healing surge.